# stylesheet_link_tag not producing links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails Tutorial at http://railstutorial.org/, chapter 4, listing 4.4. I've inserted the two lines that have calls to stylesheet_link_tag, but the links aren't being inserted into the final page. Here's my application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    <% stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
    <% stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/print',  :media => 'print'  %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the output of http://localhost:3000/pages/home

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
  <head> 
    <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title> 
    <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token"/> 
<meta name="csrf-token" content="D8xx1zqWM5qqwqdabyjy5eHLPvLY/Sxe5vEFJ816fMY="/> 
  </head> 
  <body> 
    <h1>Sample App</h1> 
<p> 
  This is the home page for the
  <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a> 
  sample application
</p> 

  </body> 
</html>
```

I've copied and pasted and typed on my own, and I'm getting the same results. Suggestions?

Thanks,
Chuck

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is producing output so it needs to be in an erb block that outputs into the template:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
```

the type of block you are using:

```
<% stylesheet_link_tag 'blueprint/screen', :media => 'screen' %>
```

does not have its result printed into the template.

Comment: In shrt, you were mssng the `=` after the `<%`.